# Angular 7: Dynamically add rows to Material data table

Tags: angular, service, datatable, angular-material

How do I add data which I get from a service into my data table dynamically?

I get data from a dialog with the service AuthenticationService. My first thought was to use `this.dataSource.push(this.transaction);`, which doesn't work.

This is how I tried to do it:

```
export class TransactionPoolComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns = ['sender', 'recipient', 'amount', 'fee'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  transaction: Transaction;


  constructor(private _AS: AuthenticationService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._AS.transaction$.subscribe( transaction => {
      this.transaction = transaction;
      this.dataSource.push(this.transaction);
      console.log(this.transaction);
      }
    );
  }
}

export interface Transaction {
  sender: number;
  recipient: string;
  amount: number;
  fee: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Transaction[] = [
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if you see the data is getting added. You need to manually call the **[`detectChanges`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)** to keep the ui updated. you can do the same with detectChanges()

you need to inject inside the constructor as,

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
```

once you assign the data just call,

```
this.dataSource.push(this.transaction);
this.ref.detectChanges();
```

also one more mistake, you need to push the element to the array and then convery to dataTable,

```
this.ELEMENT_DATA.push(this.transaction);
this.dataSource = new DataSource(this.ELEMENT_DATA));
```

Comment: How do I define the chRef?

Comment: I get the error 'Unresolved variable or type ref' now. Added the ChangeDetectorRef to the constructor.

Comment: use this.ref as you need to refer

Comment: Still doesn't update the table :/. Do you need any more information maybe?

Comment: But I'm not using DataSource at the moment ^^

Comment: you need to use that if youa re binding to mattable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185296/discussion-between-michael-and-sajeetharan).

Answer (score 2):

you must change the datasource reference.

this.dataSource = new DataSource(new Array(old + new pushed value))

Edit:

```
Because you don't use **DataSource**, you can do the following
temp = this.datasource.slice();
temp.push(value);
this.datasource = temp;
```

Comment: What type would temp be?

Comment: like datasource: Transaction[]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the reference of the dataSource and it would detect changes automatically.
Something like:

```
export class TransactionPoolComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns = ['sender', 'recipient', 'amount', 'fee'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  transaction: Transaction;


  constructor(private _AS: AuthenticationService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._AS.transaction$.subscribe( transaction => {
      this.transaction = transaction;
      // You were pushing to dataSource but your data is stored in 'data' 
      // object of dataSource, and you need to changed the reference of the 
      // dataSource by assigning dataSource to itself or assigning a new Array 
      // to dataSource and it would automatically detect the changes and 
      // update the table
      this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.push(this.transaction);
      console.log(this.transaction);
      }
    );
  }
}

export interface Transaction {
  sender: number;
  recipient: string;
  amount: number;
  fee: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Transaction[] = [
];
```